# How to retrieve every combination of numbers from 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve every combination of values from two columns in a table, where each combination matches a value in a third column.

Say part of the table looks like this:

```
products_id     options_id     options_values_id
1487            2              1
1487            2              61
1487            3              60 
1487            5              52
```

My desired output, when working with products_id 1487, would be the following two strings:

```
2-1, 3-60, 5-52
2-61, 3-60, 5-52
```

I've got the impression that those strings would need to be assembled recursively, but I ran into trouble trying it that way because not every products_id has the same options_ids, or the same number of them.

**Edited to add:** I've tried variations of a couple of the solutions below, but to no avail. I think I should have been more descriptive.

I'm trying to have it retrieve every combination of *unique* options_id and its corresponding options_values_id. (In other words, not every single possible combination of numbers from those two columns.) Options_id represents product options like "color" and "size," and options_values_id represents choices of those options, like "red" or "small." So I'm trying to come up with every possible combination of options for a given products_id. In the example above, there are two possible option combinations for that item-- "2-1, 3-60, 5-52" and "2-61, 3-60, 5-52".

Comment: Just join the table to itself

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Join the table against itself for each distinct option.**

Do a select first to retrieve the number of options.

```
$tables = array();
$rs = mysql_query(
  'SELECT DISTINCT options_id FROM table WHERE products_id = '.$id);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs)) {
  $tables[$row['options_id']] =
    'SELECT options_values_id FROM table WHERE products_id = '.$id.
    ' AND options_id = '.$row['options_id'];
}
mysql_free_result($rs);
```

Then, for each option, join it in as a separate table in your query.  Do not include any joining clauses comparing values, just join every record against every other record.

```
$sql = 'SELECT ';
$count = 0;
foreach ($tables AS $id => $query) {
  if ($count++) $sql .= ', ;
  $sql .= 'table_'.$id.'.options_values_id AS value_'.$id;
}
$sql .= ' FROM ';
$count = 0;
foreach ($tables AS $id => $query) {
  if ($count++) $sql .= ', ';
  $sql .= '('.$query.') AS table_'.$id;
}
```

Finally, execute that query.  Each row will contain one column per `options_id`.  There will be one row per unique combination of values.

Answer (score -1):

or for a mixed, php/sql approach, try using that SQL query:

```
SELECT products_id, options_id, options_values_id WHERE products_id = '$var_with_product_id';
```

fetch the results into an array, say $results:

```
$pairs = array();
foreach($results as $result) {
    // build array with pairs (array_push to avoid overwriting)
    array_push($pairs, array( $result['options_id'] => $result['options_values_id'];
}
// a bit extra complication, as array_push adds e.g. [0] => array( options_id => options_values_id ) :)
$pairs = array_values($pairs);
// check for double options_id
$found_double_options_id = false;
do {
    // check for duplicates... use a lot of array functions
} while (count($pairs) && $found_double_options_id);
```

Answer (score -1):

"Every combination" is the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join):

```
SELECT DISTINCT e1.options_id, e2.options_values_id
  FROM Entity e1, Entity e2
  WHERE e1.products_id = 1487 AND e2.products_id=1487
```